# Make fgets skip special character

Tags: c, parsing, fgets, strtok

My question is about parsing a text file using fgets. Basically there are commands that I need to parse. Once I hit a ";", anything afterwards are comments and can be skipped:

```lisp
;;
;; Very basic test - no ifs or comparisons
;;

defun main
5 3 2 * + printnum endl     ;; Should output (3 * 2) + 5 = 11
3 4 5 rot * + printnum endl ;; Should output (3 * 5) + 4 = 19
return
```

After processing:

```
defun main
5 3 2 * + printnum endl     
3 4 5 rot * + printnum endl 
return
```

In my code, I have a while loop to get each line from the text file:

```
while (fgets(str, 1000, IN)!= NULL)
        {
            len = strlen(str);
            str[len-1] = '\0'; //removes newline character
            printf("%s\n", str);
            hello = strtok(str,";");
            printf("%s\n", hello);

        }
```

I'm unsure as to how to make it where, when `strtok` sees a semicolon, it will automatically cut out anything that comes after, up until the end of the line. My attempt returns the following output:

```
 Very basic test - no ifs or comparisons


defun main
5 3 2 * + printnum endl     
3 4 5 rot * + printnum endl 
retur
```

It cuts off the last character from `return` but doesn't remove the comment after the second line of semicolons. This is pretty standard behavior no matter the contents of the text file I'm parsing. What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: What about going through your characters array and replace the first occurrence of a ";" with a \0 ? You may want to use `strchr (3)` for this.

Comment: Aside: avoid `str[len-1] = '\0';`  1) `len==0` is possible if first character read is a _null character_.  2) `'\n'` might not have been read if the line is long or the last in `IN`.  Suggest `if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n') str[--len] = '\0';`

Comment: @chux thank you, that solved the problem of it chopping off the last character of return

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a lexer for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `strtok`. As [`man strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) says:

> The `strtok()` function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more
>          **nonempty tokens**.

[...]

> From the above description, it follows that a sequence of two or more
>          contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a
>          single delimiter, and that **delimiter bytes at the start or end of the
>          string are ignored**.

(Emphasis mine.)

Whenever your line starts with one or more `;` characters, `strtok` will simply ignore them.

To solve this, you should instead search for the first occurrence of `;` in the string, and if found, replace it by `'\0'` (the NUL terminator).

Variant 1 (using `strchr` / `if`):

```
char *p = strchr(str, ';');
if (p) {
    *p = '\0';
}
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Variant 2 (`strcspn`, cheeky):

```
str[strcspn(str, ";")] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: variant 1 works, although it is my understanding that strchr returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character c in the string. I'm curious as to how this function "knows" to delete not only the occurrence of the specified token ";" but also to delete anything that comes after when we replace ";" with '\0'? I'm also noticing that where ever there was a semicolon are now black spaces. How could those be removed? (not totally necessary but could be helpful).

Comment: @J_code `'\0'` marks the end of a string. It's the same principle as `str[len-1] = '\0';` in your code: We're marking some position as the end of the string, effectively cutting of the rest. I don't understand what you mean by "black spaces"; you must have some other bug in your code.